# Opções de fechar uma pergunta com texto parcialmente não traduzido

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

A popup de opções para fechar uma pergunta está com parte to texto em inglês.
Aparentemente alguma atualização, pois há 1 dia atrás estava tudo traduzido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Além disso, quando marcamos uma pergunta como duplicada, o comentário postado automaticamente também está em inglês.

Answer (score 6):

Enviei no traducir:

- Duplicate of...: https://pt.traducir.win/string/12047
- Off-topic because...: https://pt.traducir.win/string/12068
- Needs more focus: https://pt.traducir.win/string/12042
- Opinion-based https://pt.traducir.win/string/12052

Marquei todas como urgente, se acharem que existe tradução melhor basta enviarem lá, se tudo estiver nos conformes iremos aguardar o processo de aprovação.

Comment: Também posso enviar traduções?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes pode sim, se entra no https://pt.traducir.win/ clica em `Log in!`, vai pedir sua conta da SE, pronto.

Comment: Dei uma mexida no opinion-based, tinha sobrado um inglês no texto do link.