# Por que os títulos das sinalizações ficaram em inglês no SOpt?

Tags: bug, tradução

Até um tempo atrás, as sinalizações na SOpt estavam completamente em português, porém agora elas estão em inglês. Isso é algum bug ou fizeram de propósito ?

Eu vi que existem outras perguntas que apresentam problemas parecidos como [essa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6777/op%C3%A7%C3%B5es-da-tela-de-sinaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-est%C3%A3o-em-ingl%C3%AAs), porém já faz mais ou menos 1 mês que as sinalizações estão em inglês, e estão apenas em inglês os títulos, sendo bem diferente dos problemas das outras perguntas.

Se isso foi proposital, porque fizeram isso ? Certamente isso vai dificultar bastante para pessoas que não possuem muito ou nenhum conhecimento em inglês.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Duplicata de [Opções de fechar uma pergunta com texto parcialmente não traduzido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8077/op%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-fechar-uma-pergunta-com-texto-parcialmente-n%c3%a3o-traduzido) ... Leia sobre o traducir: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7515/3635

Comment: De tempos em tempos isso acontece, eles fazem alguma atualização no site e algumas traduções "quebram". Neste caso, acredito que tenha sido por causa [desta mudança](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/401803). De qualquer forma, é incrível como um dos sites mais acessados do mundo (e um dos maiores sobre programação) não consegue ter uma solução decente para internacionalização... :-(